# Laravel Best Practice for Unique Fields Based on Variable

Tags: laravel

I'm having a really hard time trying to define this title. Essentially, my `patients` table needs a unique identifier column, and we accomplish this by concatenating the patient's first and last names and date of birth. What I would like to do is find a way to check this against the database before attempting to insert it, and displaying an error message. Here is what I currently have:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'doctor' => 'required|integer',
    'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'dob' => 'required|date_format:"m/d/Y"|max:255',
]);

$dobFix = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->dob));
$unique_id = $request->first_name . $request->last_name . $dobFix;

$patient = new Patient();
$patient->last_name = $request->last_name;
$patient->first_name = $request->first_name;
$patient->dob = $dobFix;
$patient->unique_id = $unique_id;
$patient->save();

$message = 'Patient ' . $request->first_name . ' ' . $request->last_name . ' was successfully added.';

return redirect()
    ->route('patients.index')
    ->with('success', $message);
```

When I try to submit a duplicate entry with this, I receive the following laravel error page:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 
'DuaneBartelli1986-06-22' for key 'patients_unique_id_unique' (SQL: 
insert into `patients` (`last_name`, `first_name`, `dob`, `unique_id`, 
`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Bartelli, Duane, 1986-06-22, 
DuaneBartelli1986-06-22, 2018-11-13 13:16:37, 2018-11-13 13:16:37))
```

So, this is telling me what I need to know, but doesn't help the user at all. How can I accomplish changing this into an error message like the success one that displays or perhaps making it validate with the rest of the request information?

Comment: Any reason why you're not using a unique composite key of the three columns instead of manually concatenating and storing a redundant field?

Comment: What you expect the user to do if he/she gets this error? Changing the name or birthdate? Inserting garbage data? 

The tupel of firstname + lastname + birthdate is not as unique as you might think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I accomplish changing this into an error message like the success one that displays or perhaps making it validate with the rest of the request information?

Wrap your `$patient->save();` in a try-catch that returns the user to a page with a better error message.

```
try {
    $patient->save();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return redirect('/yourUrl')->with('error', 'Your error message');
}
```